# WinRT information: Cannot find a resource with the given key. Issues with converter reference

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I get this error when starting the UWP app.  It's failing to find the FirstNameToVisibilityConverter resource.  I would really appreciate it if someone could identify why I get this error, or post a small working sample of a UWP app using a converter.  Thanks!

XAML:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyHelloWorld.HelloWorld"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyHelloWorld"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:FirstNameToVisibilityConverter x:Key="FirstNameToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </p:Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red">HI</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red">THERE</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind FirstWord}"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind SecondWord}" Visibility="{x:Bind FirstWord, Converter={StaticResource FirstNameToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <CheckBox Foreground="Red" Content="Click me to hide the first word" IsChecked="{x:Bind FirstWordChecked}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace MyHelloWorld
{
    public sealed partial class HelloWorld : UserControl
    {
        public string FirstWord { get; set; }
        public string SecondWord { get; set; }
        public bool? FirstWordChecked { get; set; }

        public HelloWorld()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class FirstNameToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if ((string)value == "Today") return Visibility.Collapsed;
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. Did you try a BreakPoint in converter and see if it is Hit?

Comment: NVM. But did you try changing your `{x:Bind}` to `{Binding}` to see if it works? `{x:Bind}` is Compile Time and `{Binding}` is Run Time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you're using the compile-time binding extension `{x:Bind}` instead of the run-time binding extension `{Binding}`, combined with the fact that the XAML compiler handles the `Converter` property as a special case, generating an explicit `LookupConverter()` method for finding the converter:

```
public global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter LookupConverter(string key)
{
    if (this.localResources == null)
    {
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement rootElement;
        this.converterLookupRoot.TryGetTarget(out rootElement);
        this.localResources = rootElement.Resources;
        this.converterLookupRoot = null;
    }
    return (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter) (this.localResources.ContainsKey(key) ? this.localResources[key] : global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources[key]);
}
```

While the normal resource lookup rules would traverse the object tree, checking each parent recursively until it found a resource of the given name, as you can see above the explicitly-generated method bypasses the `ResourceDictionary` behavior, and only looks in the root-level `Resources` (i.e. the `UserControl` object's `Resources`), or the application `Resources`.

So, you need to declare your converter resource in one of those locations. For example:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="TestSO39734815UwpResource.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestSO39734815UwpResource"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:FirstNameToVisibilityConverter x:Key="FirstNameToVisibilityConverter"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <p:Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      </p:Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Foreground="Red">HI</TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="THERE"/>
      <TextBox Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind FirstWord}"/>
      <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind SecondWord}"
                 Visibility="{x:Bind FirstWord, Converter={StaticResource FirstNameToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
      <CheckBox Foreground="Red" Content="Click me to hide the first word" IsChecked="{x:Bind FirstWordChecked}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Another alternative would be to put the resource in the App.xaml file, in the `<Application.Resources/>` element, or of course to use the `{Binding}` extension instead, which does go through the normal resource lookup process.

**Addendum:**

Personally, I feel this is a bug in the platform. The generated code-behind is accessing the framework elements anyway, so it should not be difficult to provide an implementation that would traverse the tree just as the run-time based `{Binding}` would. Some degree of limitation is understandable, but an arbitrary inconsistency like this just makes it harder to transfer WPF skills to Winrt/UWP.

As such, I went ahead and opened a bug on the Connect site: [x:Bind doesn't find converter resource](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3104689). I'm guessing Microsoft will disagree, but at the very least if we're lucky they will a) provide some rationale for the implementation decision, and b) change [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) so that this limitation is called out clearly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Peter, and I couldn't agree more that this seems buggy.  On one hand we now have a tighter object-coupling with x:Bind, but then going in the opposite direction we have to globally declare resources??  Hurt brain.

Comment: Peter, could you please update your answer to show Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=FirstNameToVisibilityConverter}}.  I needed ResourceKey= to make it work

Comment: @Sean: the code I posted is copy/paste straight from a working project. It's weird that you would have to specify `ResourceKey=` explicitly, but I assure you there should be a way to get your code to work without that. Unfortunately, I can't say for sure why it's not working in your case. It's important to note that Stack Overflow answers merely need to be useful; it's not essential (or even necessarily a good idea) that a correct answer wind up having _verbatim_ the code the question author wound up using. If the code is in fact valid, more idiomatic code is preferable.

Comment: Well, now that I've removed it again, it seems to compile as expected.  I'm not crazy.  Or don't know I am.

Comment: @Sean: you're not crazy. The XAML stuff (designer, compiler) in Visual Studio is a bit "quirky", to say the least. "Ghost" errors come and go; sometimes they are just because of a bug and Visual Studio needs to be restarted. Other times, they're related to design-time state that the editor doesn't handle very well (e.g. an error will be reported, but the code will still compile and run fine). I remain hopeful that with Microsoft essentially giving up on smartphones, they will shift their focus back to WPF and work harder to improve the developer experience there.